# Trying to change the src of an image using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, src

I have 2 html pages with an image on each one. I need to be able to click the image on the 2nd page and have it redirect me to the 1st page - with the first image.src changed to that of the second.

What is the **best/correct** way to do this? I have been trying to do it by storing the `src` in sessionStorage but it does't seem to be working. **Here is the code for `setItem`:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.images').on('click', '.groupOne', function(){
   var image = $(this).find("img"); // selects images inside group
   var imageSrc = img.first().attr("src"); // get src of first image
   sessionStorage.setItem("choice", imageSrc);
   window.location.href = 'firstPage.html';
});
</script>
```

And then to change the first image I need to use **`getItem`**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var imgTwo = sessionStorage.getItem("choice");
   var imgOne = document.getElementById("pageOneImage");
   imgOne.src = imgTwo; //sets src of img1 to src of img2
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Is there an easier way to do this using more jQuery? Thank you!

Comment: Change sessionStorage to localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but how about adding the src as a param to the query string?

On the second page:

```
window.location.href = 'firstPage.html?src=' + src;
```

And the first page:

```
var reg = new RegExp("(^|&)src=([^&]*)(&|$)", "i");
var r = window.location.search.substr(1).match(reg);
var src = r != null ? unescape(r[2]) : null;
```

Now you got the src, if redirecting from the second page.

Comment: This didn't work - but I have a feeling I am putting the code in the wrong place. Where would I place those lines on the first page?

Comment: I think it's fine to place these lines in a function, and remember to add return statement. Then just call it anywhere you like, but make sure your url correctly contains the src param.